# Why doesn't my useEffect go into an infinite loop when modifying it's dependency?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

### Code

> PrizeHistory.js

```js
...

const PrizeHistory = () =>  {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    async function getHistory () {
      try {
        let result = await sqliteInterface.getAllPrizes(db, prizeTable);
        result == null ? console.log("res is null") : setHistory(result);
        console.log("result" + result);
        console.log("history" + history);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    getHistory();
  }, [history])

  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Prize History</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

> getAllPrizes

```js
getAllPrizes(db, tableName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
          `SELECT * FROM ${tableName};`, 
          [],
          (tx, res) => {
            let len = res.rows.length;
            let results = [];  

            if(len > 0) {
              for(i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
                results.push(res.rows.item(i));
              }
            } 
            console.log("resolving promise now");
            resolve(JSON.stringify(results));
          },
          (error) => {
            reject(Error(`SQLite getAllPrizes: failed to get '*' from ${tableName}: ` + error));
          }
        );
      }); 
    });
  }
```

### The goal

When the page is mounted, set the history state to the data in the database. I initially tried this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {

    async function getHistory () {
      try {
        let result = await sqliteInterface.getAllPrizes(db, prizeTable);
        result == null ? console.log("res is null") : setHistory(result);
        console.log("result" + result);
        console.log("history" + history);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    getHistory();
  }, [])
```

but it never set my history variable correctly. I just got an empty array (which is what I inistially set the history state to). I expected the history variable to be equal to the result variable in the history `console.log()`, but it's not.

So I changed the `useEffect()` to this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {

    async function getHistory () {
      try {
        let result = await sqliteInterface.getAllPrizes(db, prizeTable);
        result == null ? console.log("res is null") : setHistory(result);
        console.log("result" + result);
        console.log("history" + history);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    getHistory();
  }, [history])
```

This code changes the history variable correctly, but I expected it to go into an infinite loop... but it didn't? Here's my logic

1. `useEffect()` has `[history]` as dependency
2. onMount, `history` is set to default value of `[]`
3. `useEffect()` sees `history` is set and begins running
4. `useEffect()` resets `history`
5. `useEffect()` **should** start again because it reset the `history` variable itself
6. Repeat 3-5 infinitely...

But it does not repeat infinitely...

### My Questions

1. Why is `useEffect()` not running infinitely when `[history]` is set as its dependency
2. Why is `useEffect()` not setting my history variable correctly on mount when it has `[]` as it's dependency.

Comment: Why do you expect useEffect() to run infinitely. "History" is a state variable. shouldn't it be executed only when the variable "history" is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your 1 question is: `history` does not change after first set because your `getAllPrizes` returns always the same value so the `useEffect` is triggered only once (on mount).

For the 2 question, the problem is that you are trying to log the `history` value right after a call to `setHistory`, which is async. If you want to log `history` each time it is updated you have to do something like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(history)
}, [history])
```

Comment: that makes sense for question 1. For question 2, the useEffect() has `console.log("result" + result);` and `console.log("history" + history);`. the second log prints out empty.

Comment: Ok, now is clear. `history` is empty because `setHistory` is async, so the `history` is not updated right after a call to `setHistory`. If you want to log the value of `history` each time it is updated you have to put a console.log inside a `useEffect` with a dep array `[history]`.

Comment: You're right. Thanks so much

Comment: @KraveXL glad I was helpful. If the answer solves your problem consider to mark it as accepted in order to help other people to find the solution quickly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not trying to set a string type on this line:

`result == null ? console.log("res is null") : setHistory(result);`

As far as I see initial type is an array and the resolve function returns a stringified object.
Do you get any warnings in the console?

Comment: Yes you are right. I already realized this and was planning to fix it once I got the variable set correctly. I can change the variable type for a state at any time. I initially set history to an array as a test. Thanks for pointing this out though